# "Another way" vs "in another way"

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions

I often meet the use of `another way` phrase both with and without the `in` preposition.

Both

> 1. Let me phrase it **in** another way.
> 2. I will put it **in** another way.
> 3. He is used to building roads **in** another way.

and

> 1. Let me phrase it another way.
> 2. I will put it another way.
> 3. He is used to building roads another way.

sound reasonable to me and I cannot clearly see any difference in the meaning. Am I wrong? May be there are better examples which do show some difference?

Comment: _Way_ can take the preposition _in_ when used as a manner phrase; or the _in_ can be omitted. It's a situation rather like _(at) home, (in) school,_ etc. It works the same with any modifier; this doesn't have anything to do with _another) -- _Put it (in) this way, not (in) that way_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, noted. What would you say about the given answer? I mean your `this doesn't have anything to do with "another"` vs `interchangeable when "another way" is being used as adverb`.

Comment: Manner phrases are a kind of adverbial phrase. It's the manner part that's significant, not the adverb part; "adverb" adds very little information, since different adverbs have different syntax.

Comment: @JohnLawler Got it, and the former answer author seems to agree. May be you compose an answer?

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but just something to think about. When the "in" is part of the verb phrase that precedes it, e.g., your second sentence in both examples, "put in," then I think there might be a case for the "in" to be retained.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang My second sentence is a bad example. There is no phrasal verb in it i.e. verb `put` is not linked to the preposition `in` here. If the phrasal verb is present: `Let me put in my plea in another way.` than it has to be kept intact either way: `Let me put in my plea another way.`.

Comment: Wasn't that what I had said :D?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I wanted to clarify that: 
**1.** There is not phrasal verb in my example #2. 
**2.** If a phrasal verb is there, the preposition **definitely has to** be retained, but only the one which is a part of that verb i.e. there would be either one or two prepositions and this does not change the initial topic.

Comment: Heh, yes, and I had covered both those points in my comment. Let me re-write my original comment.

Comment: My comment is a little off-topic, but just something to think about. When the "in" is part of the verb phrase that precedes it, e.g., as might occur in your second sentence in both examples, "put in," then I think there might be a case for the "in" to be retained.

Comment: Does this make more sense now? And I had wanted to post the original comment for other learners who might not know that there are times when they need to retain the "in."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang IMHO your second variant does not escape the ambiguity. When you say: "...need to retain the `in`", you do not mention that the retaining covers only the part of the phrasal verb and does not relate the `in` before `another`: You can say both `Let me put in my plea in another way.` and `Let me put in my plea another way.`. I did not retain the second `in` and it is perfectly ok regardless of the phrasal verb. In the same time, the first `in` is not a subject of the discussion i.e. there is no temptation to dismiss it whatsoever.

Comment: @ZverevEugene. It's not a subject of discussion for you, but this is not the case for everyone who might read this. And you and I might know all this, but others might not, which is why I had brought it up in the first place.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I do not mind bringing that up. I try to avoid ambiguity. If you bring something up, try to make the picture more clear, not obscure it.

Comment: Heh, I'm feeling obscured.

Comment: Am I the only one who went straight to *He put it in, another way*. :)

Comment: @JohnLawler Come on. Please. Help us out and compose an answer.

Comment: Nobody seems to know what the question is. There's already 5 answers, and lots of discussion.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is why I ask for your help. Your first thesis in comments sounds reasonable to me. I think that when it is made into an answer it will  not only be accepted by me but the community as well. This is the chance to purify the topic.

Comment: I am not interested in purification, whatever that might mean. The information is there already and doesn't need ritual to endorse it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Get yourself into the boots of a person who needs that piece of information. Is there a good chance that your comment is going to be found in this mess? To me the answer is no. What if you compose an answer and it is accepted and supported with votes? That no becomes a yes. The form the information is presented in might be called a mere ritual but this is what makes information available and easy to reach.

Comment: No, you're wrong about that. Answers to questions are no more findable than comments. That's why we still get the same questions over and over. Very few people bother to look; they'd rather have personal service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A predicate needs its argument to complete the meaning. An object is one as such (direct argument); the preposition phrase is another (oblique argument) but very much essential to the meaning of the sentence. The preposition is the argument marker.

Not going into pedantic details, we can say this much that in both sets of examples `WAY` is used all along as a noun. We don't find fault with the first set of examples — `IN ANOTHER WAY` — is an `Adverb Prepositional Phrase` (preposition in the beginning, its object at the end and a modifier in between; in - another - way). It fulfills oblique argument in the first set of three.

What about the rest? `WAY` is not an adverb here. `WAY` or for that matter `ANOTHER WAY` is an `adverbial objective` (they create an object like illusion though not acted upon) or `adverbial noun` i.e., nouns used as adverb:

> He works mornings and nights.

`Mornings and nights` occupy the position earmarked for an object. But a word of caution: adverbial nouns modify verbs and adjectives and they are not used to describe manners.

However, in the first two of the remaining set of three `another way` functions as adverbial objective – localising the functionality of the verbs. But in the last sentence we want `another way` to function as an adverbial objective assigning the role to describe manners which is contrary to its nature. The last sentence flouts basic rules of semantics and is **wrong** as such:

> He is used to building roads another way.

In  this example sentence the participle object phrase `building roads` can be classified as an object of another​ object `roads` usurping (leaving no room for) adverbial objective (yet another noun — `another way`). So we have:

- Building (noun equivalent participle)
- Roads (noun)
- Another way (noun)

Without a relationship word (preposition) `another way` can not be knit in the sentence coherently or logically. However, I have a sort of inner prompting that says that if `roads` be replaced by any pronoun (it/this/one) than `another way` may be induced in the sentence without a preposition but the rule underlying is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive and thorough explanation. For me and I assume for any non native English speaker it is a bit hard to chew but with due effort I get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that

3. "He is used to building roads another way." 
   is only incorrect on account of the semantic link between a road and a way.
4. "He is used to cutting grass another way." 
   would be fine.

Comment: Ambiguity doesn't make a sentence incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences sound good to me, with or without the preposition "in." But, formal writing would probably require the preposition in question.

Comment: Bravo on your first answer here. If you could flesh it out with a source that the requestor can look into, it would serve as a fuller response to help others. A personal vote such as 'sounds good to me' otherwise fits into Comments as a passing opinion, with all due respect.

Comment: By saying "sounds good to me," I meant that I consider both uses correct, although I may lean toward one or the other, depending on the context and circumstances. You can say that is an opinion. Thanks for prodding me for reason. Let me give it a try. I think what have led me to my standing opinion are my encounters with the two uses while living in an English-speaking country and Google polls. For those who have not done that before, just remember to enter your phase enclosed in quotation marks in Google Search. The number of search results can be used as an indication how common a phrase is.

Answer (score -1):

These are merely examples of unneeded prepositions. We meet them daily, such as Rachel Ray's dozen or so each day: "Mix it in", "Stir it up", "Pour it out", "Flip it over". She will say all of these phrases for any mixture that needs cooking on a flat grill or skillet. Remove every preposition, and the meaning does not change.

Sometimes the preposition does add to the meaning, such as "He despised the gun in his hand, so he threw it ___." Was that up, down, into the sea, or out the window?